# Destroying gameobjects when restart the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

In my game I am using `dontDestroyOnload` for some gameobjects to pass them on another level. Now the problem is that I don't want `dontDestroyOnload` happening when I restart the game when I die because it is producing errors.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You do it by tracking your Don't destroy objects and destroying them yourself. Instead of using dontDestroyOnload maybe you should be passing state between sceens via userprefs.

Comment: u mean `PlayerPrefs` or `userPrefs` ?  @ScottChamberlain